# Integration using summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

How do you integrate $\sqrt{x}$ from an arbitrary constant $a$ to another $b$ by summation ?

Comment: It is probably an interesting question with interesting answers. Do you mean by a limit of Riemann sum type argument?

Answer (score 2):

Let us divide the region $a\le x\le b$ into $n$ sub-region as $a,ar,ar^2,\cdots ar^n=n$ such that $\delta_i=ar^i-ar^{i-1}$

If real $m\ne-1,$

$$\int_a^b x^mdx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{1\le i\le n}(ar^i)^m\delta_m\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{1\le i\le n} (ar^i)^m(ar^i-ar^{i-1})\right)$$

$$=a^{m+1}\lim_{r\to1}(r-1)\sum_{1\le i\le n} (r^{i-1})^{m+1} $$

$$=a^{m+1}\lim_{r\to1}(r-1)\sum_{1\le i\le n} (r^{m+1})^{i-1} $$

$$=a^{m+1}\lim_{r\to1}(r-1)\cdot1\cdot\frac{(r^{m+1})^n-1}{r^{m+1}-1} $$

$$=a^{m+1}\lim_{r\to1}\frac{\left(\frac ba\right)^{m+1}-1}{\frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}} $$ as $\frac ba= r^n\implies (r^{m+1})^n=(r^n)^{m+1}=\left(\frac ba\right)^{m+1}$

$$=(b^{m+1}-a^{m+1})\cdot\frac1{\lim_{r\to1}\left(\frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}\right)}$$

$$=(b^{m+1}-a^{m+1})\cdot \frac1{(m+1)\cdot1^m}$$

$$\text{  as }\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=nx^{n-1} \text{ using L'Hospital Rule }$$

Comment: I recall reading that Fermat used this method. The idea of going through an interval with a geometric progression (rather than the obvious linear progression) is ingenious and not immediately obvious. It makes the solution much easier. This makes me wonder if some other subdivision of the interval (or other problem space) would produce an unexpectedly easy solution to some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

$f(x)= \sqrt{x}$,

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{x}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{b-a}{n} \sum_1^n\sqrt{x_i}$$

Comment: yes i meant that

Comment: This is called Riemann Sum to integral transformation. You can read about it [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-riemann-sum-formula-for-the-definite-integral.html)

Comment: @Inceptio It isn't entirely clear over what argument your sum runs. Still +1 though :).

Comment: @cruise: I will make necessary changes if you could tell what is wrong?

Comment: @Inceptio I wouldn't say 'wrong'. It's just a bit odd though to my mind that you did not specify what you are summing over (your sum starts from 1, not from for instance $i=1$). Never mind though.

Comment: Yes. Yes. That's what I meant. $i=1$, actually, I thought it is *understood*.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is nondecreasing, every Riemann sum associated to the subdivision $s=(x_i)_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is between $R^+(s)$ and $R^-(s)$ with
$$
R^-(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sqrt{x_{i-1}},\qquad R^+(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sqrt{x_{i}}.
$$
If the mesh of $s$ is $\delta(s)$,
$$
R^+(s)-R^-(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})(\sqrt{x_{i}}-\sqrt{x_{i-1}})\leqslant\delta(s)\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{x_{i}}-\sqrt{x_{i-1}}.
$$
Thus, $R^+(s)-R^-(s)\leqslant\delta(s)(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})\to0$ when $\delta(s)\to0$, that is, the function is Riemann integrable. Furthermore, for every $i$,
$$
(x_i-x_{i-1})\sqrt{x_{i-1}}\leqslant\tfrac23(x_i\sqrt{x_i}-x_{i-1}\sqrt{x_{i-1}})\leqslant(x_i-x_{i-1})\sqrt{x_{i}},\qquad (\ast)
$$
hence
$$
R^-(s)\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^n\tfrac23(x_i\sqrt{x_i}-x_{i-1}\sqrt{x_{i-1}})\leqslant R^+(s),
$$
and the sum in the middle is telescoping hence all this shows that
$$
\int_a^b\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm dx=\tfrac23(b\sqrt{b}-a\sqrt{a}).
$$
Finally, the result hinges on the algebraic inequalities $(\ast)$, which we now prove.

Dividing $(\ast)$ by $\frac13(\sqrt{x_i}-\sqrt{x_{i-1}})\gt0$ and renaming $\sqrt{x_{i-1}}=x$ and $\sqrt{x_i}=y$, one must show that, for all $0\leqslant x\lt y$,
$$
3x(y+x)\leqslant2(y^2+yx+x^2)\leqslant3y(y+x),
$$
or,
$$
-(y-x)(2y+x)\leqslant0\leqslant(y-x)(y+2x).
$$
Since $y-x\gt0$, $2y+x\gt0$ and $y+2x\gt0$, this proves $(\ast)$.